# Custom View accepting aliased resource

Tags: android

What is the best way to resolve an [Alias Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) from a custom view?

**Resource**

```
<array name="alias">@array/resource</array>
<array name="resource" >
    <item>@drawable/image1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image2</item>
</array>
```

### XML Form

*Passing Alias Resource to Custom View*

```
<dev.packge.CustomView
   xmlns:toolbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   toolbox:drawables="@array/alias" />
```

*Initializing Custom View*

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
int drawables = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_drawables, -1);
TypedArray resultTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(drawables);
```

### Code Form

*Passing Alias Resource to Custom View*

```
CustomView c = (CustomView) new CustomView(getActivity());
c.setDrawables(R.array.alias);
c.Initialize();
ViewGroup.AddView(c);
```

*Initializing Custom View*

```
public void Initialize(){
  TypedArray resultTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(mDrawables);
```

## Problem Statement

In both forms (from XML or from Code), the resultTypedArray is empty when passing an aliased resource. But this code will work when passing the @array/resource or R.array.resource directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer... [array aliasing isn't support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)

> Note: Not all resources offer a mechanism by which you can create an alias to another resource. In particular, animation, menu, raw, and other unspecified resources in the xml/ directory do not offer this feature.